# How can I set a dropdown button on a top navbar as active in Semantic-ui?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I looked into Semantic-ui doc, but couldn't find how I should proceed to set a dropdown item as `active` (not open) in my top navbar menu, same as for the regular items.

The `active` class is used to open them, while it is used to highlight regular menu links.

To rephrase it, when I am in one of the routes of that menu dropdown item, I want to highlight it, same as for a link, but I don't know what the class I should use.

I started to make my own css class for that but I am pretty sure they have a keyword for that, and I wanted to check this.

---

EDIT: I made up somethiong quickly, tested for inverted menus, secondary or not. However, this question still stands.

```
.menu:not(.secondary) .dropdown.item.current{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  color: #fff !important;
}
.menu:not(.secondary) .dropdown.item.current:after{
visibility: visible!important;
z-index: 100!important;
background: #3d3e3f !important;
margin: 0 !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
border: none !important;
}
.menu.inverted .dropdown.item.current{
border-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the dropdown item to just be highlighted and not be opened, include a 'selected' class in the element and not 'active' class